# How does a jenkins pipeline differ from a MultiBranchPipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How does a pipeline project differ from a MultiBranchPipeline Project.

I am using a pipeline defined in the Jenkinsfile which comes from SCM.

My Context is more than one developers working on many branches of a bitbucket repo.

Answer (score 1):

The Multi-Branch Project looks in the branches of a repository for files called `Jenkinsfile` and sets up (deletes) jobs on-the-fly as they (dis-)appear.

The Pipeline project type only works with a single branch.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at the Bitbucket branch source plugin, 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin

This will then create the Jobs (and branch jobs) dynamically based on webhooks when repos are created and have a Jenkinsfile committed to them. So you no longer need the gui to create a multibranch job for each repo.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, When you need dynamic management of your branches in jenkins you would use Multibranch Pipeline and if you want to manage(setup/create/delete job in jenkins) each brach individually you will use a pipeline.

In your context, where multiple developer are working and creating different/many branches, Multiple Pipeline solution will be better for you. As there is no headache of job creation/deletion on the user.

Pipeline and Multiple Pipeline both work with jenkins file from scm